# H.265/HEVC support for HLS in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, hevc, h.265, transport-stream

Currently, HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) requires the content to be video H.264 and/or AAC/MP3/sound.

Is there support for H.265/HEVC for HLS in iOS 9? If not, is there any way to bypass this limitation and use TS files that are H.265 encoded?

Comment: There is no documentation, so you just have to try it and see. Remember it will only work on phones with the HEVC decoder. 6 has one, but it was disabled, and I doubt it will be enabled vis a software upgrade due to licensing. 6s supposedly can play HEVC in MP4. So I would think 6s will do HLS HEVC. but you never know with apple.

Comment: Have you tried playing the stream with VLC? VLC has supported H.265 since iOS 7 I believe.